# Route network traffic through another server and then to VPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing

I have 2 virtual machines:

1. VM A in DMZ subnet
2. VM B in Core subnet

The VM A is able to access servers on the other side of a VPN IPsec tunnel and also reach Internet.
The VM B is "client" and it's not able to access anything.

Both VMs are running Ubuntu OS 22.04 LTS.

Scheme:

[Internet + VPN] <-> VM A <-> VM B

How can I access Internet and servers on the other side of the VPN IPsec connection from the VM B?

I enabled ipv4 forwarding, set iptables in the VM A. I also set static route in the VM B to the VM A as a gateway. It's not working - tried curl, tried apt update, watched tcpdump but it's all dead.

Comment: You would need additional routes on whichever router acts as the default gateway for the core and DMZ subnets. Because the two VMs are not in the same subnet, your static route on VM B takes no effect as VM A's address is not directly reachable.

Comment: Hmmm so if I am unable to access physical router and set the additional routes I am basically screwed. Anyway if VM B will be in the same subnet it will be working or I need some sort of NAT and LAN routing features running on the VM A?

Comment: Certainly you have a much better chance of making this work if both VMs are in the same subnet. You could just about work around them being in separate subnets by adding another tunnel (e.g. GRE) between the two VMs which you could then route over, but that adds complexity. Hard to tell whether you'd need more NAT without seeing the IP addressing scheme. VM A should not need any more routing features beyond the IP forwarding you enabled.

Comment: I made it within the same subnet. Anyway the idea with a VPN tunnel is interesting. It's not ideal as you wrote but in certain situation it can help. Thanks :)